# Tibco ems multiple consumers

Tags: c#, client, tibco, ems

I am very new to tibco ems and  have a question related to scenario where I have multiple consumers and one producer queue. If I am using client ackg mode, can all consumers consume different messages in parallel ? Consumers are on different machines and I want to set up tibco ems in a way so that all consumers can work on different messages concurrently. Also, if any of the consumers fails to send acknowledgement, how redelivery will happen?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use client ack mode you can have different consumers work on different messages. When messages aren't acknowledged and the client connection is terminated, the message will be released back into the queue (and the redelivery count will be incremented). In your client code, you might want to check if the redelivery count is higher than 0 and have some logic to make sure you don't handle messages twice (if that is a concern).